# Having problems using weather-js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Some monthes ago I followed a tutorial to code a bot that shows weather forecast depending on a stated location. This bot is using weather-js package, but since recently, no matter if I host my bot or launch it through the console, it's working when it wants to, and not working for some locations.
Here is what contains my index.js :

```
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
\\client.on("ready")....
.....
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    let command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    if (command === "weather") {
        client.commands.get("weather").execute(message, args, Discord, weather)
      }
    });
```

and what my weather.js contains:

```
var weather = require('weather-js');

const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'weather',
    description: "Used to get the weather of a place",
    execute(message, args, Discord, weather) {
  
      const city = args[0]
  
      weather.find({search: args.join(" "), degreeType: "C"}, function(error, result){
  
        if (error) return message.channel.send(error)
        if (!city) return message.channel.send("You must specify a location please!")
  
        if (result === undefined || result.length === 0) return message.channel.send("**Invalid location**")
  
        let current = result[0].current
        let location = result[0].location
  
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Weather forecast for ${current.observationpoint}`)
        .setDescription(current.skytext)
        .setThumbnail(current.imageUrl)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField("Temperature: ", current.temperature + "°C", true)
        .addField("Wind Speed: ", current.winddisplay, true)
        .addField("Humidity: ", `${current.humidity}%`, true)
        .addField("Timezone: ", `UTC${location.timezone}`, true)
  
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
  
      })
  
    }
  }
```

I always got that same error when it doesn't work:

```
 throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
```

There's even some locations that were working before, but that suddenly stopped working for any reason!
Has someone had the same problems with weather-js, or is it coming from the code?

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your line on embed should be a null. That's why its throwing an error. To prevent this. You can use an **OR** operator.

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Weather forecast for ${current.observationpoint || "NO DATA"}`)
.setDescription(`${current.skytext || "NO DATA"}`) //Using a direct call can cause an error.
.setThumbnail(current.imageUrl) //If this part is the culprit let me know
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setTimestamp()
.addField("Temperature: ", `${current.temperature || "NO DATA"} °C`, true)
.addField("Wind Speed: ", `${current.winddisplay || "NO DATA"}`, true)
.addField("Humidity: ", `${current.humidity  || "NO DATA"}%`, true)
.addField("Timezone: ", `UTC${location.timezone  || "NO DATA"}`, true)
  
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
```

The **||** symbols is a *OR* operator.

Comment: I've tested with your code, and everything works well!
Many thanks! :D

Comment: Im glad that I could help.